# SSL certificate shows different domain

Tags: apache, ssl

I have two sites setup on an apache webserver, both are on HTTPS. The certificates are properly installed and they work on almost all browsers, but on some IE versions I get a certificate error message when I open the A site, and the certificate info shows the domain name of the B site. I checked both urls with different SSL checkers and they seem to be fine. Also other browsers show the correct certificate.
Does anybody have any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you narrow down which IE versions? If the browser doesn't do Server Name Indication, the server doesn't know which certificate to present until it already has established an encrypted connection, possibly with the wrong cert.

Comment: For old IEs (and other old browsers which do not support SNI) you need one IP address per HTTPS enabled site or a certificate with multiple domain names.

Comment: Possible SNI issue. SNI support is related to the OS version rather than the browser version. Its is supported in IE 7 or later in Vista or higher not in XP or Server2003 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Web_browsers.5B6.5D